# Why do the inequalities for planar graphs apply only if it is simple?

Tags: inequality, graph-theory

For planar, simple, connected graphs, with v≥3, we have e≤3v-6.
If the length of the smallest circuit is 4, e≤2v-4.
etc
The proof of the inequalities is based on Euler's Formula which relies only on the graph being connected and planar, why must the graph be simple to apply these inequalities?

Comment: Read the proofs, and it ought to become clear

Comment: @Arthur I wrote down the proof myself, and it relies on Euler's Formula and the fact that the sum of the degrees of the faces is equal to double the edges of a planar graph. However those two lemmas do not rely on the graph being simple, which is why I do not understand how it follows that the graph must be simple for the inequalities to apply.

Comment: Then consider this: What step in your proof does not work for a graph with three vertices and 45 edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What's the smallest number of edges a face can have in a simple graph? In a non-simple graph?